# MPI IO - MPI_FIle_seek - How to calculate correct offset size for shared file

Tags: file, mpi, offset

Update. Now the junk is removed from the end of the shared file, but ther is still som "junk" in the middle of the file where process 0 ends writing and process 1 starts writing:

10 4 16 16 0 2 2 3 1 3 4 2 4 5 1 0 4 6 2 8 5 3 8 10 4 9 5 4 ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@10 4 16 16 1 2 6 0 3 5 2 2 2 8 1 5 6 5 6 6 4 8 9 7 6 2 1 3 6 4 10 2 5 7 7 6 10 6 5 9 9 10 6 7 5 8

However if i count the the jiberish, i get to 40. When i try to do;

```
offset = (length-40)*my_rank;
```

It works, but it is not a very scalable and robust solution. Therfor i need to compute this number for a more generell solution. Does anybody see how can be done, here is my current function:

```
#define MAX_BUFF 50
int write_parallel(Context *context, int num_procs, int my_rank, MPI_Status     status){
int written_chars = 0;
int written_chars_accumulator = 0;
int n = context->n; 

void * charbuffer = malloc(n*MAX_BUFF);
if (charbuffer == NULL) {
exit(1);
}

MPI_File file;
MPI_Offset offset;
MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,"test_write.txt",
    MPI_MODE_CREATE|MPI_MODE_WRONLY,
    MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);

written_chars = snprintf((char *)charbuffer, n*MAX_BUFF, "%d %d %d %d\n", n, context->BOX_SIDE, context->MAX_X, context->MAX_Y);
if (written_chars < 0){ exit(1); }
written_chars_accumulator += written_chars;

int i,j;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){   
if(context->allNBfrom[i]>0){
    written_chars = snprintf((char *)charbuffer+written_chars_accumulator,     (n*MAX_BUFF - written_chars_accumulator), "%d %d %d ", i, context->x[i], context->y[i]);     
    if (written_chars < 0){ exit(1); }
    written_chars_accumulator += written_chars;

    for(j=0;j<context->allNBfrom[i];j++){

        written_chars = snprintf((char *)charbuffer+written_chars_accumulator, (n*MAX_BUFF - written_chars_accumulator), "%d ", context->delaunayEdges[i][j]);    
        if (written_chars < 0){ exit(1); }
        written_chars_accumulator += written_chars;
    }
    written_chars = snprintf((char *)charbuffer+written_chars_accumulator, (n*MAX_BUFF - written_chars_accumulator), "\n");     
    if (written_chars < 0){ exit(1); }
    written_chars_accumulator += written_chars;
}
}
int length = strlen((char*)charbuffer); 
offset = (length-40)*my_rank;   //Why is this correct? the constant = 40    needs to be computet in some way...
//printf("proc=%d:\n%s",my_rank,charbuffer);
MPI_File_seek(file,offset,MPI_SEEK_SET);
MPI_File_write(file,charbuffer,length,MPI_CHAR,&status); 
MPI_File_close(&file);      
return 0;
}
```

Her is my current result, with this solution which is also correct: 10 4 16 16 0 2 2 3 1 3 4 2 4 5 1 0 4 6 2 8 5 3 8 10 4 9 5 4 10 4 16 16 1 2 6 0 3 5 2 2 2 8 1 5 6 5 6 6 4 8 9 7 6 2 1 3 6 4 10 2 5 7 7 6 10 6 5 9 9 10 6 7 5 8

But it will not scale because, I dont know how to compute number of jiberish elemtens. Does anybody have a clue ?

Comment: I forgot to add this in the top; MAX_BUFF = 50, n = 10 (in this example)

Comment: Please, format the code (last "}" is out of the block, and extra new-lines would improve readability) and output better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code your goal is to remove the NULL-chars in between your text blocks. In this parallel writing approach there is no way to solve this without violating the safe boundaries of your buffers. None of the threads now how long the output of the other threads is going to be in advance. This makes it hard (/impossible) to have dynamic ranges for the write offset.

If you shift your offset then you will be writing in a aria not reserved for that thread and the program could overwrite data.

In my opinion there are two solutions to your problem of removing the nulls from the file:

1. Write separate files and concatenate them after the program is finished.
2. Post-process your output-file with a program that reads/copy chars form your output-file and skips NULL-bytes (and saves the result as a new file).

Comment: "When a process calls a collective I/ O function, however, the
implementation knows exactly which other processes will also call the same collective
I/ O function, each process providing its own access information. The implementation
may, therefore, choose to wait for all those processes to reach the
function" , From the book; 'Using Advanced MPI: Modern Features of the Message-Passing Interface', ch7 page 202. Are you sure that dynamic calculation of the string length is impossible?

Comment: There is no way to predict the correct output without running the code first, so yes I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

> offset = (length-40)*my_rank;   //Why is this correct? the constant = 40    needs to be computet in some way...

The way you compute this is with `MPI_Scan`.  As others have pondered, you need to know how much data each process will contribute.

I'm pretty sure I've answered this before. Adapted to your code, where each process has computed a 'length' of some string:

```
length = strlen(charbuffer);
MPI_Scan(&length, &new_offset, 1, MPI_LONG_LONG_INT, 
                      MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
new_offset -=length; /* MPI_Scan is inclusive, but that 
                   also means it has a defined value on rank 0 */
MPI_File_write_at_all(fh, new_offset, charbuffer, length, MPI_CHAR, &status);
```

The important feature of MPI_Scan is that it runs through your ranks and applies an operation (in this case, SUM) over all the preceding ranks.  Afte r the call, Rank 0 is itself.  Rank 1 holds the sum of itself and rank 0; rank 2 holds the sum of itself, rank 1 and rank 0... and so on.